# Remote Desktop Windows 10 over OpenVpn network

Tags: windows, openvpn, remote, desktop

I have  an OpenVpn Access server(V2.7.4) being hosted on a VPS. My goal is to remote desktop into to another client connected to the VPN server sitting in another city (both running Win10 pro). My understanding is that, provided the proper permissions are set, if the two computers are connected to the same VPN they should be able to see each other and I would able to remote into it using the IP assigned to the client. This works if I am sitting right next the remote computer on the same LAN but not when both clients connect from different networks.

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong here?  Clearly my understanding is incomplete or wrong. In the OpenVPN access server settings I have enabled Inter Client communication. Perhaps I am missing certain permission settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the client-to-client setting in your OpenVPN server.conf or that you allowed the traffic between two clients in your netfliter configuration

It should work as a local network

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solved the problem by configuring the private subnet for each user.